# Sencha Touch - Best method to download thousands of rows from server to local sqlite?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sencha-touch

I have a MySQL database on my server that I would like to be able to backup to a SQLite databse on a sencha touch app (for offline use).  What would be the best method to iterate through and grab the data (I am using PHP on the server and can send it as JSON, XML, CSV, or whatever is necessary).

EDIT: This is the SQLite proxy I am using... [source](https://github.com/tomalex0/SenchaTouch-v2-SqliteProxy)